# CETAS equivalent in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

It is possible to read data from Azure blob storage in Azure SQL database via openrowset or bulkinsert.

But is it possible to upload a file in blob through any SQL commands in Azure SQL DB ?
Similar to CETAS in Azure Synapse.

Comment: Just use Data Factory Copy activity to copy your data out.

Comment: Hey @wBob Thank you for your reply
, my requirement is to trigger an ADF pipeline in case of any data change in a table and not have it scheduled for every 5 min etc.
So what I was thinking is create a trigger in Azure SQL db based on DML and in case if there is possibility to upload a file in blob from Azure SQL DB; do it via trigger.
This file would act as a source for event trigger of ADF.

S

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that seems to be current limitation for SQLDB. below link has the details [PolyBase features and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-versioned-feature-summary?view=sql-server-ver15)